# Html5 resizing object by dragging

Tags: javascript, html

I need to resize notes in my little application, but I don't know how. They have to be resized by dragging their bottom right corner and it must be done in pure java script.

Div with "+" adds new note and empty div is something like counter of all notes.

Code:

```js
document.addEventListener("onload", Load());
 var index = 0;
 var cnt = 0;
 var x = 0;
 var y = 0;
 var xx = 0;
 var yy = 0;
 var clicked = false;
 var dragged = false;
 var counter = 0;
 var numberOfPapers = 0;
 var state = 0;
 
 
 function Load(){
  var adder = document.querySelector("#add");
  adder.setAttribute("onclick", "addClick()");
 }
 
 function addClick(){
  cnt++;
  numberOfPapers++;
  document.querySelector("#counter").innerHTML = "Przebieg = " + cnt + "<br>" + "Liczba kartek = " + numberOfPapers;
  var paper = document.createElement("div");
  var paperX = document.createElement("div");
  var paperR = document.createElement("div");
  var paperS = document.createElement("div");
  //papierek xD
  paper.setAttribute("class", "paper");
  paper.setAttribute("onmousedown", "movePaper(this,event)");
  paper.setAttribute("onmouseup", "stop(this)");
  paper.setAttribute("onmouseleave", "stop(this)");
  paper.setAttribute("id", "id_" + cnt);
  paper.style.top = "100px";
  paper.style.left = "100px";
  paper.style.zIndex = cnt;
  //niszczyciel papierków
  paperX.setAttribute("class", "deleter");
  paperX.setAttribute("onclick", "deletePaper(this)");
  //zmieniacz rozmiarów
  paperR.setAttribute("class", "resizer");
  paperR.ondragstart = function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();
   };
  paperR.setAttribute("onmousedown", "resize(this,event)");
  //edytor tekstu tini emce
  paperS.setAttribute("class", "txtEditor");
  paperS.setAttribute("onclick", "editTxt()");
  
  paper.appendChild(paperX);
  paper.appendChild(paperR);
  paper.appendChild(paperS);
  
  document.body.appendChild(paper);
 }
 
 function stop(e){
  e.setAttribute("onmousemove", null);
  state = 1;
 }
 
 function resize(e,event){
  state = 2;
  
 }
 
 function deletePaper(e){
   e.parentElement.id = "del";
   var del = document.querySelector("#del");
   del.parentNode.removeChild(del);
   numberOfPapers--;
   document.querySelector("#counter").innerHTML = "Przebieg = " + cnt + "<br>" + "Liczba kartek = " + numberOfPapers;
  }
 
 function movePaper(e, event){
  index++;
  e.style.zIndex = index;
  x = event.clientX;
  y  = event.clientY;
  xx = e.style.left;
  yy = e.style.top;
  xx = xx.slice(0,xx.search("px"));
  yy = yy.slice(0,yy.search("px"));
  x = x - xx;
  y = y - yy;
  
  e.setAttribute("onmousemove","moreMove(this,event)");
 }
 
 function moreMove(e,event){
  e.style.top = event.clientY - y + "px";
  e.style.left = event.clientX - x + "px";
 }
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
  
 #add{
  position: absolute;
  width: 45px;
  height: 35px;
  top: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  background-color: #F5574E;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  }
 
 #counter{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 25px;
  right: 80px;
  background-color: #F5574E;
  text-align:center;
  border: solid black 1px;
  }
 
 .paper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background-color: #E3D67F;
  border: solid black 1px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
  }
  
 .deleter{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  }
  
 .resizer{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: green;
  }
 
 .txtEditor{
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="add">+
</div>
<div id="counter">
</div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener("onload", Load());` should likely be `document.addEventListener("onload", Load);`

Comment: but it's not working when I change Load() to Load in this place :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply take replicate your move functions and instead of targeting top and left you target width and height of the parent node. Like this:

```
function resize(e, event) {
    event.stopPropagation();//this to prevent move behavior to be triggered when clicking resize handle
    state = 2;
    index++;
    e.style.zIndex = index;
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    xx = e.parentNode.style.width;
    yy = e.parentNode.style.height;
    xx = xx.slice(0, xx.search("px"));
    yy = yy.slice(0, yy.search("px"));
    x = x - xx;
    y = y - yy;

    e.setAttribute("onmousemove", "resizeMove(this,event)");
}

function resizeMove(e, event) {
    console.log('resixe')
    e.parentNode.style.height = event.clientY - y + "px";
    e.parentNode.style.width = event.clientX - x + "px";
}
```

You'll have to declare width and height of your parentNode for it to work, you can add it to your paper section.

```
paper.style.width = "100px";
paper.style.height = "100px";
```